Can SQL Server contained database users use linked servers with login mappings?
Using SQL Server 2022 Standard Edition and contained database users (which means no corresponding SQL login at the instance level).  I would like to have the contained database users be able to use a linked server, and specifically with the contained user mapped to use a specific username/password on the remote database.  When I try to add the mapping using SSMS, I get the error

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
'username' is not a valid login or you do not have permission. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15007)

My interpretation is that this linked server user mapping feature only works with instance-level logins and is not possible when the local login is a contained database user.  However, I cannot find any explicit Microsoft documentation of this limitation.
Can anyone confirm my understanding, or am I missing something that would make this possible?

why do you believe that after some year the behaviour changes, have you asked the support about it?

I had frankly forgotten asking the original question, and didn't see it when I searched.  But this is a newer version of SQL Server (2022 vs 2017) so it's possible the behavior has changed - would be nice if someone could verify.


However, I cannot find any explicit Microsoft documentation of this
limitation.

This is not straightforward, you need to put two things together.
1.

In the contained database user model, the login in the master database
is not present. Instead, the authentication process occurs at the user
database. The database user in the user database doesn't have an
associated login in the master database.

contained database users
2.

[ @locallogin = ] N'locallogin' A login on the local server.
@locallogin is sysname, with a default of NULL. NULL specifies that
this entry applies to all local logins that connect to @rmtsrvname. If
not NULL, @locallogin can be a SQL Server login or a Windows account.
The Windows account must have access to SQL Server directly, or
through membership in a Windows group.
A default mapping between all logins on the local server and
remote logins on the linked server is automatically created by
executing sp_addlinkedserver. The default mapping states that SQL
Server uses the user credentials of the local login when connecting to
the linked server on behalf of the login. This is equivalent to
executing sp_addlinkedsrvlogin with @useself set to true for the
linked server, without specifying a local user name. Use
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin only to change the default mapping or to add new
mappings for specific local logins.

sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
3.

local_principal_id    int Server-principal to whom mapping applies.

sys.linked_logins
All these put together tells you that while creating linked server you create a mapping between local logins and remote logins and you can see them in sys.linked_logins as ids, those ids are id from sys.server_principals that do not exist while using contained databases so the mapping cannot be created.
All the links used in my answer refer to SQL Server 2022 so nothing was changed for linked servers.
